# Google and links containing commas and encoded commas problem

Tags: url, seo, uri, google-search-console, googlebot

I'm working with a large website with a huge amount of already indexed pages.
The links, including those in sitemaps unfortunately include ',' (commas).
eg.
site.com/article/article-one,420.html

Now, the problem is that google (as i see in search console) sometime breaks those links apart and causes executing additional crawling to address that ends before comma sign.
eg.
site.com/article/article-one

My goal is to prevent this behaviour. As an attempt to fix it I've already tried to change links in one of the smaller sitemaps by using encoded comma ( %2C ) but those links were not indexed due to google finding another already indexed site with the same cannonical.
My conclusion is that google treats those links as new, as if those two were different:

site.com/article/article-one,420.html

site.com/article/article-one%2C420.html

Is there any way to make google stop cutting original links on comma sign?